# How to fixes Ionic no working in cordova 5.0.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

cordova Update to 5.0.0 plugins the new version is renamed when I run " hello ionic start blank" or sidemenu , I have problems, this is what has the terminal , i have mac OS X Yosemite

**mac os version Yosemite**

Creating Ionic app in folder /home/miguel/Cordova/hello based on sidemenu project

```
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================] 100% 0.0s

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/archive/master.zip
[=============================] 100% 0.0s

Update config.xml
Initializing cordova project
running cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
WARNING: org.apache.cordova.device has been renamed to cordova-plugin-device. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device and cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device.
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via cordova plugins registry
Fetching from cordova plugins registry failed: EACCES, mkdir '/home/miguel/tmp/npm-3493-DFp6DkqV'
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.device2
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.device2
Fetching from npm failed: 404 Not Found: org.apache.cordova.device
Error: 404 Not Found: org.apache.cordova.device
at RegClient. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at streamreadable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
running cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
WARNING: org.apache.cordova.console has been renamed to cordova-plugin-console. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console and cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console.
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via cordova plugins registry
Fetching from cordova plugins registry failed: EACCES, mkdir '/home/miguel/tmp/npm-3506-WhGg6OTV'
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.console1
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.console1
Fetching from npm failed: 404 Not Found: org.apache.cordova.console
Error: 404 Not Found: org.apache.cordova.console
at RegClient. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Request. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:876:14)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at streamreadable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
running cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
Fetching plugin "com.ionic.keyboard" via cordova plugins registry
Fetching from cordova plugins registry failed: EACCES, mkdir '/home/miguel/tmp/npm-3519-Pc7mh_MZ'
Fetching plugin "com.ionic.keyboard" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/com.ionic.keyboard
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/com.ionic.keyboard
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to this,

move into your project folder hello and install the cordova plugin directly from their GitHub using the below command

```
 $ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

for more detail check the issue on [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-add-plugins-perhaps-your-version-of-cordova-is-too-old/3807)

Hopes this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/new-cordova-5/21558/5

"WARNING: org.apache.cordova.device has been renamed to cordova-plugin-device. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device and cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device.
WARNING: org.apache.cordova.console has been renamed to cordova-plugin-console. You may not be getting the latest version! We suggest you cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console and cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console."

and

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist